# Getting Sentinel-2 raster values for points on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, zonal-statistics, band

I am calculating TSM and chlorophylle in a river, for each parameter I used a function to create a new band that gives me information about each one. First I want to calculate the mean value for several points on these new bands. I found this option to calculate it: [Extracting Raster Values for Points](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/extract-raster-values-for-points?hl=en)  Apparently there is no error in the script, however it doesn't return any values (*null*).

Here is my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ad15e9b021ec82edafb10556339d86c

```js
Map.centerObject(puntos_sierpe,20);

// Función para añadir objetos al mapa
Map.addLayer(rio_sierpe.draw('navy'), {}, "Río y Laguna Sierpe",0);


////////////////// Colección de imágenes//////////////////////////



// Cargamos la función que enmascara píxeles nubosos (copiada y pegada de EE catalogo de datos)


/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
}
//Se declara la variable de la coleccion de imagenes y se filtra por fecha y region de interes
var s2_ic_filt = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
                  .filterBounds(puntos_sierpe)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                  
                  

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

print(s2_ic_filt,'Colección de imágenes Sentinel-2 filtrado por fecha y región');

//
Map.setCenter(-83.4746, 8.8679, 12);

//Se agrega la capa con un promedio .mean() de las imágenes

Map.addLayer(s2_ic_filt.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');

var bandas = s2_ic_filt.first().bandNames();
print (bandas, "Bandas Sentinel 2");


////////////////CLIP TO COLLECTION IMAGES



// Funcion para recortar con los limites del rio
var rio_bounds = function(image) {
  // Recorte con AOI
  return image.clip(AOI);
};


//Recorte a coleccion de imagenes del rio
var S2Clipped = s2_ic_filt.map(rio_bounds);

print(S2Clipped,"Coleccion recortada");

Map.addLayer(S2Clipped,visualization, "RGB Colección recortada", false);



///Programar SST usando una expresion 
var addSST = function(image) {
  var SST = image.expression(
    '-229.34 * ((GREEN/NIR) ** 3 )+ 1001.65 * ((GREEN/NIR) ** 2) - 1422.7 * (GREEN/NIR) +665.7', {
      'GREEN': image.select('B3'),
      'NIR': image.select('B8')

    }).rename('SST');

  return image.addBands(SST);
};

var SST_IC = S2Clipped.map(addSST);


print(SST_IC.first().bandNames());
//SE DEBE AÑADIR LA PROPIEDAD SYSTEM:TIME_START
//SST = function (image){
//        return image.copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  
//};


print (SST_IC,'Colección Sólidos Suspendidos Totales');

//Parametros de visualizacion, el maximo y el minimo fueron elegidos empiricamente
// como puedo probar que es mejor para la visualizacion
var vis= {
  min:-500,
  max:500,
  palette: [
    'midnightblue', 'blue', 'mediumblue', 
    'aqua', 'lime', 'limegreen', 'yellow',
    'sandybrown','orange', 'crimson',
    ]
};

Map.addLayer(SST_IC.first().select("SST"),vis,"Clorofila -primera imagen-");

function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  };
}

function zonalStats(ic, fc, params) {
  // Initialize internal params dictionary.
   var _params = {
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: null,
    crs: null,
    bands: null,
    bandsRename: null,
    imgProps: null,
    imgPropsRename: null,
    datetimeName: 'datetime',
    datetimeFormat: 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
  };
  

  // Replace initialized params with provided params.
  if (params) {
    for (var param in params) {
      _params[param] = params[param] || _params[param];
    }
  }

  // Set default parameters based on an image representative.
  var imgRep = ic.first();
  var nonSystemImgProps = ee.Feature(null)
    .copyProperties(imgRep).propertyNames();
  if (!_params.bands) _params.bands = imgRep.bandNames();
  if (!_params.bandsRename) _params.bandsRename = _params.bands;
  if (!_params.imgProps) _params.imgProps = nonSystemImgProps;
  if (!_params.imgPropsRename) _params.imgPropsRename = _params.imgProps;

  // Map the reduceRegions function over the image collection.
  var results = ic.map(function(img) {
    // Select bands (optionally rename), set a datetime & timestamp property.
    img = ee.Image(img.select(_params.bands, _params.bandsRename))
      .set(_params.datetimeName, img.date().format(_params.datetimeFormat))
      .set('timestamp', img.get('system:time_start'));

    // Define final image property dictionary to set in output features.
    var propsFrom = ee.List(_params.imgProps)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var propsTo = ee.List(_params.imgPropsRename)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var imgProps = img.toDictionary(propsFrom).rename(propsFrom, propsTo);

    // Subset points that intersect the given image.
    var fcSub = fc.filterBounds(img.geometry());

    // Reduce the image by regions.
    return img.reduceRegions({
      collection: fcSub,
      reducer: _params.reducer,
      scale: _params.scale,
      crs: _params.crs
    })
    // Add metadata to each feature.
    .map(function(f) {
      return f.set(imgProps);
    });
  }).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.notNull(_params.bandsRename));

  return results;
}

//Definir puntos en los que se va a muestrear

//INTENTO 1//var ptsMuest = puntos_sierpe.map(bufferPoints(5, false));//

//Se ingresan las coordenadas
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.603159, 8.795126]), {plot_id: 1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.558605,8.798594]), {plot_id: 2}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.532207,8.835373]), {plot_id: 3}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.64279,8.77518]), {plot_id: 4}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.56068,8.79372]), {plot_id: 5}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.53346,8.82995]), {plot_id: 6}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.51864,8.85087]), {plot_id: 7}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.50655,8.857849]), {plot_id: 8}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-83.47217,8.857989]), {plot_id: 9})
]);

var ptsMuest = pts.map(bufferPoints(5, false));

Map.addLayer(ptsMuest,["blue"],"Puntos clorofila",1);
Map.setCenter(-83.603159, 8.795126,11);


// Define parameters for the zonalStats function.
var params = {
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10,
  bands: [23],
  bandsRename:['SST'],
  crs: 'EPSG:5070',
  datetimeName: 'date',
  datetimeFormat: 'YYYY-MM-dd'
};




// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var ptsStats = zonalStats(SST_IC, ptsMuest, params);
print(ptsStats);
```